# How to fix 'Tag already exists' even though git ls-remote results in no tag found

Tags: git, groovy, tags

I'm currently working on a Jenkins pipeline. I'm using Gitlab as Repository and Groovy for the Pipeline script.
The workflow is the following:

1. `git init <FOLDER>`
2. `git fetch --tags --progress <REPO> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
3. `git config remote.origin.url <REPO>`
4. `git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
5. `git config remote.origin.url <REPO>`
6. `git checkout -f <LONGCOMMITHASH>`
7. `git branch -a -v --no-abbrev`
8. `git checkout -b <BRANCH> <LONGCOMMITHASH>`

This is done automatically with the Groovy git command. Here the manually written steps for tagging:

1. `git ls-remote --exit-code --tags origin <TAG> || echo 'not found'`
2. `git tag <TAG>`
3. `git push origin --tags`

**git ls-remote** responds with 'not found', but **git tag** says 'fatal: tag 'TAG' already exists'

If i trigger the pipeline a second time it works because **git ls-remote** says the tag does exists so not **git tag** is trigger. But nothing between the two runs was changed.

I already checked if all the config is set correctly and it is. Also i was not able to reproduce the problem and it occurs rarly randomly.

With my understanding the **git ls-remote** in the first run correctly responded with "not found" and should have tagged it. Though the tagging went wrong with a fatal error.

Comment: it looks like your tag is created locally by a not shown command. Why do you check the remote location for tag, not the local one?

Comment: according to several pages, retrieving the tags is normally done by git ls-remote, therefore i used it correspondingly. yet you are right, since the repository is freshly clone both local and remote should deliver the same result.
except these commands there should be no interaction with git, though :/

Comment: it makes sense to check remote tags before pushing tags. it makes sense to check local tags before creating them. I guess you need 2 separate checkers in your case. Most likely your 'git tag' failed but 'git push' succeeded and the remote got the tag which already existed. your next checker on remote detected it.

Comment: i guess it would be necessary to check both, yet the push did not happen since the pipeline failed and finished without the push :(